# How do I use unsafe values in an enum?

Tags: c#, interop, enums, unsafe

I need to use this enum in my C# application, but it won't let me use these values. When I specify the type as uint I can use the -1 value, and when I specify int I can't use the last 2 values. Is there a way to use the unchecked keyword here to allow me to define all of these values? These values are coming from an external source, so I can't change them.

```
internal enum MyValues : int
{
    value1 = -1,
    value2 = 0,
    value3 = 0x80000000,
    value4 = 0xFFFFFFFF
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `-1` to be a different value from `0xFFFFFFFF`, you're going to need a datatype bigger than 32 bits. Try `long`.

Comment: Using a 64bit data type isn't an option, I'm using interop to return a 32bit value.

Comment: If -1 and 0xFFFFFFFF are technically the same thing when using a uint, I guess I can just remove the -1 value?

Comment: @Jon: -1 doesn't exist when you're using uint - you'd have to make an unchecked conversion.

Comment: I know that -1 doesn't exist, I want it to overflow and wrap around. I guess if it did that, -1 would just be 0xFFFFFFFF, correct?

Comment: @Jon T : Exactly. The two's complement representation of -1 has all bits set - so in 32 bits, this is the same as `0xFFFFFFFF` as an unsigned.

Comment: This answer doesn't really meet the requirement "These values are coming from an external source, so I can't change them". [user551751's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312977/1331851) follows the pattern that the  [microsoft/CsWinRT](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT) project uses for interop generation.

Comment: @npjohns does that project have any examples of enums that have both `-1` and `0xffffffff` as members?

Comment: @AakashM It generates interop code from winmd files, I don't know of a specific winmd with an enum example. [Here is a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hi1ruB) of unchecked working to make them both -1 though.

Comment: @npjohns I added `Console.WriteLine($"{Test.Test1 == Test.Test2}");` and I got `True`. I stand by my assertion that "If you want -1 to be a different value from 0xFFFFFFFF, you're going to need a datatype bigger than 32 bits."

Comment: That statement is true, but it was not what was was asked for in the question. If the external system defines 2 constants with the same value, making one different would break the communication contract.

Comment: @npjohns I'm not sure what you're after here. The asker was satisfied, [and understands that they are the same value when coerced to 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262340/how-do-i-use-unsafe-values-in-an-enum/2623449?noredirect=1#comment2636306_2623449).

Answer (score 5):

0xFFFFFFFF is a 32 bit number, so it should be fit to enum : int
( I feel long type is an overkill :) )

Have you tried

```
enum YourEnum : int { /*...*/, value4 = unchecked( (int)0xFFFFFFFF ) };
```

Answer (score 2):

Since these values look to be constant, just create a static class to hold the values. Also, you can use whatever types you want:

```
public static class MyValues
{
    public const int value1 = -1;
    public const int value2= 0;
    public const int value3 = 0x80000000;
    public const int value4 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use normal values for the `enum` (0, 1, 2, 3), and create a class or a pair of methods to convert the incoming values to the `enum` members and vice-versa.

Comment: Wrote this big long post and then noticed you said the same thing. +1. @Jon Tackabury: @Jon Seigel's answer is the most maintainable option. Do not assume -1 is the same as 0xFFFFFFFF unless you have very intimate knowledge of the library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try ulong enums instead of int?